# Software center disappeared after installing exelearning

Tags: software-center

I have installed Ubuntu today and everything worked pefectly. But I must have done something wrong because I cannot find or install the Software Center.
I tried to install the authoring programm `exelearning`. There was a problem in the installation and now, when I search in the dashboard for `software center` the icon and name of `exelearning` appears.
I have tried this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

And this is what I got:

```
beatriz@beatriz-LIFEBOOK-A512:~$ apt-get install software-center
E: No se pudo abrir el fichero de bloqueo «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permiso denegado)
E: No se encontró un archivo de réplica «/var/lib/dpkg/»
```

Any help? Since I have only installed some applications until now, I could also re-install Ubuntu and start from zero again. But I would like to solve this problem and specially to know what I did wrong to avoid it in the future.

Thanks,
Beatriz.

---

@enedil: sorry for the misuse of comments/answer question. I'm new here. Won't happen again.
@enedil, @Leon95:
Thanks for your efforts and help. Nothing worked, possibly because I have some lacks of knowledge. I have reinstalled Ubuntu 10.4 again, I had just started to intall programms and it is the faster solution. I have realized also the Bluetooth icon and the applications Gimp and VLC and maybe others disappeared. I start from zero again.

Comment: Please, translate error message to English.

Comment: Sorry, here the English message:beatriz@beatriz-LIFEBOOK-A512:~$ apt-get install software-center E: could not find the blocking file «/var/lib/dpkg/lock» - open (13: Permission denied) E: did not find a mirror file «/var/lib/dpkg/».

Comment: It's still Spanish or Portuguese. I can't distinguish. And edit your question, not add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the **`sudo`** in your second expression if this is what you typed in.
If the command `software-center` works you can restore the starter:

- Open gedit (Type gedit in the "Dash Home")
- Insert the following text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Software Center
GenericName=Software Center
Comment=Lets you choose from thousands of applications available for Ubuntu
Exec=/usr/bin/software-center %u
Icon=softwarecenter
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=PackageManager;GTK;System;Settings;
MimeType=application/x-deb;application/x-debian-package;x-scheme-handler/apt;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-center
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#ffbf87
Keywords=Sources;PPA;Install;Uninstall;Remove;Purchase;Catalogue;Store;Apps;
```

- Save it as '**Software Center.desktop**' in the folder 
  '**/home/*YourName*/.local/share/applications**'
- Drag it into the Starter bar